# Issue with scraping zomato.com

Tags: beautifulsoup

I cannot iterate through the list of restaurants.
Here is a quick video demonstrating my issue: https://streamable.com/vorg7

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/san-francisco/restaurants?q=restaurants&page=1",headers=headers)
content = response.content
bs = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")


zomato_containers = bs.find("div", {"class": "ui cards"})

restaurant_title = zomato_containers[1].find("a", {"class": "result-title hover_feedback zred bold ln24   fontsize0 "}).text

print("restaurant_title: ", restaurant_title)
```

I expect Python to state that there are 15 restaurants in 1 page, but I am getting 39.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the class you use to find your results, and used a `find_all` method to get all the snippet cards, and I've found 15 restaurants:

**CODE:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("https://www.zomato.com/san-francisco/restaurants?q=restaurants&page=1",headers=headers)
bs = soup(response.text,"html.parser")

zomato_containers = bs.find_all("div", {"class": "search-snippet-card"})
print(len(zomato_containers))

for zc in zomato_containers:
    restaurant_title = zc.find("a", {"class": "result-title"})
    print("restaurant_title: ", restaurant_title.get_text())
```

**RESULT:**

```
15
restaurant_title:  Delfina    
restaurant_title:  Boudin Bakery  
restaurant_title:  In-N-Out Burger   
restaurant_title:  Hollywood Cafe 
restaurant_title:  The Slanted Door   
restaurant_title:  Tartine Bakery
restaurant_title:  The Original Ghirardelli Ice Cream and Chocolate...
restaurant_title:  The Cheesecake Factory          
restaurant_title:  Scoma's        
restaurant_title:  Boulevard   
restaurant_title:  Foreign Cinema        
restaurant_title:  Zuni Café
restaurant_title:  Brenda's French Soul Food       
restaurant_title:  Gary Danko
restaurant_title:  Hog Island Oyster Company
```